# Delete image from folder using data list delete button

Tags: asp.net, button, datalist

I display some images in a datalist by getting the images from folder. 
Now, I want to delete the image in folder when I click the Delete button on my datalist .

Here is my delete button code:

```
protected void delete_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = sender as string;

        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));

        FileInfo fInfo;

        fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        fInfo.Delete();

        gvImages.DataBind();
    }
```

I don't know  how to get the exact image name which I want to delete, there is a delete button with each image.

Here is my datalist:

```
<div>
   <asp:DataList ID="gvImages" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" GridLines="Horizontal"
            runat="server" BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowHeader="true">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 90px; height: 90px">
                                <img id="PICID" runat="server" src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' alt='' style="height: 100px;
                                    width: 100px;" />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="Delete" Height="22px" OnClick="delete_onClick" Width="100px" runat="server"
                                    Text="Delete Picture" /><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesting functions as you have done is a poor programming practice:

```
 File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));
```

Try is like this and then when you debug, you will be able to see what file you are are trying to delete:

```
string fileName = e.CommandArgument;

fileName = Server.MapPath(fileName);

File.Delete(fileName);
```

Also, are you getting an error?  An exception?  Why isn't there an exception handler around the code?

Answer (score 0):

you should use commandName on button.  And you should use OnDeleteCommand on DataList.

```
  <div>
       <asp:DataList OnDeleteCommand="Delete_Command" ID="gvImages" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" GridLines="Horizontal"
                runat="server" BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowHeader="true">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <center>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 90px; height: 90px">
                                    <img id="PICID" runat="server" src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' alt='' style="height: 100px;
                                        width: 100px;" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="Delete" Height="22px" CommandName="Delete" Width="100px" runat="server"
                                        Text="Delete Picture" /><br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:DataList>

    </div>
```

Then,

For example Hold FileName:

```
<asp:Button CommandArgument ='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```

Then,

```
  public void Delete_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
  { 
        //you can hold filename on Button's  CommandArgument 
        string fileName = e.CommandArgument;

        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));

        FileInfo fInfo;

        fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        fInfo.Delete();

        gvImages.DataBind();
  }
```